# Remove all but two trailing zeros AND thousand separator

Tags: sql, postgresql, number-formatting

*Postgres Version 11.7*

I am trying to remove trailing zeros *beyond two decimal places*, while also adding thousand separator to my result set.

*Example 1* produces the desired result; all trailing zeros were removed:

```
SELECT to_char(54354.0010, 'FM99 999 999 990.999999'); --> returns 54 354.001
```

*Example 2* illustrates the problem:

```
SELECT to_char(54354.0000, 'FM99 999 999 990.999999'); --> returns 54 354.
```

In *Example 2* all zeroes after the decimal are removed.
But the desired result would be:

```
54 354.00
```

The result should always have a minimum of two decimal places, regardless whether they are zero or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces your desired result:

```
SELECT to_char(54354.0000, 'FM99 999 999 990.009999')
```

Two `0` instead of `9` after the decimal point.
[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE)

> `9`   digit position (can be dropped if insignificant)
> `0`   digit position (will not be dropped, even if insignificant)